# When does the entity get detached in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have seen in many posts that if the tracking is not enabled, the entity is detached.

What I would like to know is: how can there be few objects which are not tracked and a few which are tracked?

Can someone share the code snippet which shows that this entity is not tracked by a context.

According to **MSDN**:

Detached: the entity is not being tracked by the context
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx

According to following post which I read:
http://blog.maskalik.com/entity-framework/2013/12/23/entity-framework-updating-database-from-detached-objects/

```
var entry = _context.Entry<T>(entity);

if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Detached objects, or objects that are created outside of Entity Framework (EF), don’t have automatic tracking enabled.

And creating a POCO class in code-first approach is one such example of a detached entity.

Is this the only scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more scenarios for the `Detached Object`.

1.You dont want to track an entity.

```
var entity= context.MyEntities.AsNoTracking().Where(...).FirsOrDefault();
```

In this query entities retrieved are not tracked hence any changes on the entities will not be recorded to database.

Consider this.

```
entity.Name = "1";
context.SaveChanges();
```

> As this entities are not tracked the changes will not be saved
>   unless you attach this.

```
var entry = _context.Entry<T>(entity);

if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

2.Consider your working on disconnected architecture (API,Web). Consider an employee API which have PUT endpoint.

**This would attach the employee to the context and update the entity as context is not aware of this entity.**

> Advantage : No need to fetch the employee entity from the database.
>   Disadvantage : Someother user changes the entity between the transaction might be losed (you can still update property that are only changed)

```
public void UpdateEmployee(Employee entity)
{
     var entry = _context.Entry<Employee>(entity);

    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
      _context.Attach(entity);
       entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    } 

    Context.SaveChanges()
 }
```

Second Version

```
public void UpdateEmployee(Employee entity)
{
    var dbItem = context.EmployeeEnities.FirstOrDefault(g=>g.Id==entity.Id);

    //Context is already have track of this entity, you can just update properties you have changed.
    dbItem.Name = entity.Name;

    Context.SaveChanges()
 }
```

Comment: There is one more case when an entity is detached: This is after SaveChanges() are called: Unchanged, Modified and Added entities are set to Unchanged, while detached and deleted entities are detached.

Comment: @Eldho I agree with your httpput and  employee api.